# Scrapyd launch failure at an imported droplet, DO

Tags: digital-ocean, scrapyd, droplet

A server image has been exported and imported into a new DO account. I've created a droplet of it with authentication thru SSH keys rather than password authentication, see note.
Now it's on, yet, as in the console I launch **scrapyd** the following issue is out:

Note

> "Droplets that use SSH keys have password authentication disabled by
> default. This makes them secure against brute-force attacks."

```
root@scrapyd-server-2-6june2023-s-1vcpu-1gb-fra1-01:/# scrapyd   
[-] Loading /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scrapyd/txapp.py...  
[-] Basic authentication disabled as either `username` or `password` is unset  
[-] Scrapyd web console available at http://207.154.203.148:6800/  
[-] Loaded.  [twisted.scripts._twistd_unix.UnixAppLogger#info] twistd 22.10.0 (/usr/bin/python3 3.9.2) starting up.  [twisted.scripts._twistd_unix.UnixAppLogger#info] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.  
[stderr#error] Traceback (most recent call last):  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1334, in startListening  [stderr#error]     skt.bind(addr)  
[stderr#error] OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address  
[stderr#error] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  
[stderr#error] Traceback (most recent call last): 
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/bin/scrapyd", line 8, in <module>  
[stderr#error]     sys.exit(main())  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/scrapyd/scripts/scrapyd_run.py", line 18, in main  
[stderr#error]     run()  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 35, in run  
[stderr#error]     app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 674, in run  
[stderr#error]     runApp(config)  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 29, in runApp  
[stderr#error]     runner.run()  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 374, in run  
[stderr#error]     self.postApplication()  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 254, in postApplication  
[stderr#error]     self.startApplication(self.application)  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/scripts/_twistd_unix.py", line 444, in startApplication  
[stderr#error]     service.IService(application).privilegedStartService()  
[stderr#error] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 271, in privilegedStartService  
[stderr#error]     service.privilegedStartService()  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/application/internet.py", line 115, in privilegedStartService  
[stderr#error]     self._port = self._getPort()  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/application/internet.py", line 139, in _getPort  
[stderr#error]     return getattr(  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 369, in listenTCP  
[stderr#error]     p.startListening()  
[stderr#error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 1336, in startListening  
[stderr#error]     raise CannotListenError(self.interface, self.port, le)  
[stderr#error] twisted.internet.error.CannotListenError: Couldn't listen on
207.154.203.148:6800: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address.
```

**Any way out ?**

### Update

As I have done a new droplet out of the same image with *a password authentication*, yet **the error log is the same** as I run `scrapyd`.